# I want to calculate payments with 4 Due days in Excel

Tags: excel

DATE    INVOICE No. INVOICE AMOUNT  Current WEEK 1  WEEK 2  WEEK 3

```
14/01/2016  1   543             
15/01/2016  2   327             
16/01/2016  3   445             
17/01/2016  4   65              
18/01/2016  5   357             
19/01/2016  6   45              
20/01/2016  7   450             
21/01/2016  8   342             
22/01/2016  9   221
```

Payment will paid by every Friday,
How to do it in Excel...

Comment: This is not a question, this is you asking us to do your job.

Comment: Plus the question is fairly ambiguous in the first place. Do you need some kind of notification 4 days before hand, or do you need some kind of "find every friday" method?

Answer (score 0):

You could make anonther column where you store the [week number](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/WEEKNUM-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340), starting with saturday.

`=WEEKNUM(A1;16)`